# Entity Framework infinite loop

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am using entity framework to load my data using this statement:

```
 var data = db.ChargingSpots.Include(x=> x.Relation_ChSpot_ChType_.Select(s => s.ChargerType)).ToList();
```

but the issue i am facing is that enters to an infinite loop because the relation between (ChargingSpots and ChargerType) tables are many to many so i made a table between them to handle this which is (Relation_ChSpot_ChType) how to handle this loop ?

Comment: Maybe you have a wrong join and the result is a N x M cardinality ? How many records do you have on the two tables ?

Comment: chargingSpots table has: ChargerSpotID, Arabic Name, English Name, Description, LocLat, LocLong, isPrivate.
ChargerTypes table has: ChargerTypeID, Description, IsUniversal.
Relation_ChSpot_ChType) has: ID, ChargingSpotID, ChargerTypeID

Comment: what makes you think you have an infinite loop ?

Comment: I traced my code and the data was in a loop